# Why "Contact Form 7" doesn't update PHPmailer library?

Tags: plugins, security, updates, plugin-contact-form-7, phpmailer

I realized that popular Wordpress plugin `Contact Form 7` uses this library https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.

When I check source of mail, which has been sended from Contact Form 7, it looks like this:

```
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.14 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
X-WPCF7-Content-Type: text/plain
```

So, this version is from (Nov 1st 2015).

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/changelog.md

The latests one is:

> Version 5.2.18 (December 24th 2016)
>
> **SECURITY** Critical security update for CVE-2016-10033 please update now! Thanks to Dawid Golunski.

Why Contact Form 7 uses old versions of PHPMailer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHPMailer is not part of the plugin, it is [shipped with WordPress](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/a3ea7ea2e977864e2402776508b92f521ad53260/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php). So it is up to WordPress to keep it up to date. There is a patch already in ticket [#37210](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37210).

In the mean time, you can [create a mu-plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins), include the newer version of PHPMailer here, create an instance and assign it to the global variable `$phpmailer`. WordPress will then use *that* instead of its own outdated version. But be aware that WordPress’ version has some changes that are not compatible with the original class, so you might break some plugins.